# What is the most efficient way to check if item exists in Arraylist?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, collections

What is the most efficient way to do this ?

I have a  ArrayList list called windowList.

GameWindow is bean having startTime and endTime.

For each object i recieve, I need to check the window of the object belongs to any of this windowList values. I need to do it for millions of values.

Please help me with most effeftive way to do this ....

Comment: Can you add class code for objects you receive and what "belongs" in your question means?

Comment: Most efficient would be to have your elements in a sorted collection and performing hashed or binary search.

Comment: I have edited my answer; I think it should answer your need nicely

Comment: I disagree with the fact that this question is answered by the mentioned question, sorry...

Comment: Reason for the call to reopen: this is a XY problem; while OP asked to check the presence of an element in a list, in fact his problem is far different from that: it is a problem of intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: drop your `ArrayList` and go with `SortedMap`s. We are supposing two things here:

- your start and end times are `long` (note: code written for Java 7);
- your `GameWindow` class implements `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` correctly.

Given these prerequisites, write a dedicated class (say, `GameWindowList` or something) in which you declare:

```
final SortedMap<Long, List<GameWindow>> startTimes = new TreeMap<>();
final SortedMap<Long, List<GameWindow>> endTimes = new TreeMap<>();
```

Adding a window is then:

```
public void addGameWindow(final GameWindow window)
{
    final long startTime = window.startTime();
    final long endTime = window.endTime();
    List<GameWindow> list;

    // Insert in start times
    list = startTimes.get(startTime);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        startTimes.put(startTime, list);
    }
    list.add(window);

    // Insert in end times
    list = endTimes.get(endTime);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        endTimes.put(endTime, list);
    }
    list.add(window);
}
```

Looking the windows for a given time is then:

```
public List<GameWindow> getWindowsForTime(final long time)
{
    // Submap of start times where the time is lower than or equal to
    // the requested time
    final SortedMap<Long, List<GameWindow>> validStartTimes 
        = startTimes.headMap(time);
    // Submap of end times where the time is greater than or equal to
    // the requested time
    final SortedMap<Long, List<GameWindow>> validEndTimes 
        = endTimes.tailMap(time);

    // Why GameWindow must implement equals and hashCode
    final Set<GameWindow> startSet = new HashSet<>();
    final Set<GameWindow> endSet = new HashSet<>();

    // Insert into the start set all game windows whose start time
    // is less than or equal to the requested time
    for (final List<GameWindow> list: startTimes.headMap(time).values())
        startSet.addAll(list);

    // Insert into the end set all game windows whose end time
    // is greater than or equal to the requested time
    for (final List<GameWindow> list: endTimes.tailMap(time).values())
        endSet.addAll(list);

    // Only retain the intersection of both sets
    startSet.retainAll(endSet);

    // Return the result
    return new ArrayList<>(startSet);
}
```

The two key elements are:

- `SortedMap`'s `.{tail,end}Map()` filter out immediately all windows whose either start or end time are not legal;
- `HashSet` is used to retain only the intersection of windows for which both the start time  and end time are legal; hence the importance of `GameWindow` implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()`.